Unexpected closing of tcp/tls connection in golang
In the following snippet, by calling the Client.Disconnect(), error happens because the struct has a nil tls connection.
The logic i followed was this: Client struct handles higher level messages, Connection struct handles lower level messages and the *tls.Conn itself. So connection is embedded into the client (maybe badly implemented now due to not doing dependency injection, but doesnt matter at this point of time). Client is used in main() twice:

first time to Connect()
second time to Disconnect()

Once Client.Connect() is called, it will call further Connection.Connect() which will further call tls.Dial() and save the *tls.Conn into the Connection struct.
Since this is all contained by the client, i thought that calling Client.Disconnect() in main() is ok since all other things were never dereferenced and the connection should not have been closed.
Further investigating with wireshark showed that client seems to be sending a Fin flag in the packet to close the connection. Where does this happen?
Since i read a line in the Connection.Connect(), i thought this might be the reason, but with the check at the end of the Connect() function, *tls.Conn is still not nil.
Can someone explain what is happening here?
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "crypto/tls"
)

type Command interface {
    line() string
}

type ListCommand struct{}

func (c ListCommand) line() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("LIST\r\n")
}


type Client struct {
    hostname string
    port     int

    connection Connection
}

func NewClient(hostname string, port int) Client {
    return Client{
        hostname:   hostname,
        port:       port,
        connection: Connection{},
    }
}

func (c Client) Connect(username string, password string) error {
    err := c.connection.connect(c.hostname, c.port, username, password)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (c Client) Disconnect() error {
    return c.connection.disconnect()
}

func (c Client) SendCommand(command Command) Response {
    reader, err := c.connection.send(command.line())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error happened during send command in client", err)
    }

    return Response{reader: reader}
}


type Connection struct {
    conn *tls.Conn
}

func (c Connection) connect(hostname string, port int, username string, password string) error {
    config := &tls.Config{}

    news_server := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", hostname, port)

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", news_server, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error happened during auth", err)

        return err
    }

    c.conn = conn

    err = c.conn.Handshake()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error happened during handshake", err)

        return err
    }

    log.Println("connection established, starting read...")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(c.conn)
    response, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error reading response during handshake", err)
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println(response)
    fmt.Println(string(response))

    if conn == nil {
        log.Println("error, connection closed at the end of connect", err)

        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (c Connection) disconnect() error {
    if c.conn == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("c.conn is nil")
    }

    return c.conn.Close()
}

func (c Connection) send(str string) (*bufio.Reader, error) {
    if c.conn == nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("c.conn is nil")
    }

    n, err := c.conn.Write([]byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error happened during command send", n, err)

        return nil, err
    }

    return bufio.NewReader(c.conn), nil
}


type Response struct {
    reader    *bufio.Reader
    lines     [][]byte
    header    []byte
    is_parsed bool
}

func (r Response) Parse() error {
    var err error

    r.header, err = r.reader.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err)
        return err
    }

    r.is_parsed = true

    return nil
}

func (r Response) StatusCode() int {
    status_code_string := strings.Split(string(r.header), " ")[0]

    val, err := strconv.Atoi(status_code_string)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error converting status code number", err)
        return 0
    }

    return val
}


func main() {
    NNTP_SERVER := "news.domain.com"
    NNTP_PORT := 563

    client := NewClient(NNTP_SERVER, NNTP_PORT)

    err := client.Connect("test", "test")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error during connection", err)
    }

    err = client.Disconnect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error during disconnection", err)
    }
}



It would really help you to create a minimal reproducible example when you encounter a problem like this, which will almost inevitably show you where the problem is in the first place. None of the network stuff matters at all here, the field is "unexpectedly" nil because you are using value receivers in your methods, so changes to the receivers are not visible between method calls. Using a tools like staticcheck can help point these out for you too, with checks like "ineffective assignment" (though that won't flag conn since you do read it within the method)
